# Queried Data as Datapoints on Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am trying to plot chart using Chart.JS based on my data from database. Here number of Labels and their values will come directly from the query result. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
<?php
function getValsOfCategoryLabels(){
    $yValsWithLabels = "";
    ......
    // some codes to make query on db and get result in $queryResult variable
    ......
    ......

    foreach($queryResult as $data){
        $x0 = $data0['name'];
        $total = $data0['total'];
        $yValsWithLabels = $yValsWithLabels. "{y: ".$total.", label: \"".$x0."\"}, ";
    }

    return $yValsWithLabels;
}

?>
var categoryLabelsNdVals = [<?php echo getValsOfCategoryLabels() ?>];
var hourlyCategoryBarChart = new CanvasJS.Chart("columnchartContainer",    {

  animationEnabled: true,
  axisX: {
  labelFontSize: 16
  },
  axisY: {
  title: "",
  labelFontSize: 13
  },
  legend: {
  verticalAlign: "bottom",
  horizontalAlign: "center",
  fontSize: 16
  },
  theme: "theme2",
  data: [

  {        
  type: "column",  
  showInLegend: true, 
  legendMarkerColor: "grey",
  legendText: "Name of Category",
  dataPoints: categoryLabelsNdVals
  }   
  ]
});

hourlyCategoryBarChart.render();
```

Now for the given datapoints (which is in "{y: Some_Value, label: Some_Name}" format) I am not getting any chart as output, unless I explicitly declare all the y-axis values and label names myself, which fails reflect database info.

What is the right way to accomplish my objective?

Comment: What does `var categoryLabelsNdVals = [<?php echo getValsOfCategoryLabels() ?>];` show if you view the source of your page?

Comment: I just have checked and found that 'categoryLabelsNdVals' does not get initialized with any value as there was a little mistake to send the  'yValsWithLabels' array to 'categoryLabelsNdVals' and javascript thinks 'categoryLabelsNdVals' as a string variable. Now I have made yValsWithLabels' a string and now 'categoryLabelsNdVals' gets loaded with intended values from db, but still no chart gets drawn

Comment: There must still be something wrong with categoryLabelNdVals.  Can you view source of your page and show a snippet of this?  Everything you have should work when you get the data array sorted out.  Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wnqd7cqk/1/

Comment: here is the source: http://imgur.com/D55SDNr

Comment: The fiddle is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/wnqd7cqk/2/.  Note that I changed the empty ("") label to a space (" "), but it still charted without this modification.  I don't know what's wrong if yours isn't plotting at all.

Comment: Thing is whenever value is set to categoryLabelsNdVals manually, chart is drawn, but when used query result to fetch that, it does not